# Complex solutions within unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

How many solutions within a unit circle $|z| < 1$ does the equation $(1 +
z)^{n + m} = z^n$ have for $z$ complex, and $n$, $m$ positive integers?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: I searched my files and questions! Honestly I can't remember where this question comes from!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some partial solutions, found empirically with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=all+solutions+of+%281%2Bz%29%5E16%3Dz%5E2%2C+%7Cz%7C%3C1):

- For $n=0$, there are $2k-1$ solutions for $m \in [6k-5,6k+0]$.
- For $n=1$, there are $2k+0$ solutions for $m \in [6k-4,6k+1]$.
- For $n=2$, there are $2k+1$ solutions for $m \in [6k-3,6k+2]$.

Based on these, I conjecture that are $2k+n-1$ solutions for $m \in [6k-5+n,6k+n]$.

This gives $2\left\lceil \dfrac{m-n}{6} \right\rceil +n -1$ solutions in the general case.

*I'd love to see a proof!*